# Using bound pattern variables from an OR group to test conditional elements in CLIPS rules

Tags: clips

I would essentially like to create 1 rule that will fire if either of 2 facts are above a certain value, i.e. a rule with the following LHS:

```
(or
    (object-0 (value ?x))
    (object-1 (value ?y))
)

(test
    (or
        (> ?x 1)
        (> ?y 2)
    )
)
```

**The problem** is that this won't work if one of those objects doesn't exist. This makes perfect sense because you can't operate on a variable that doesn't even exist.

I would *really* like to avoid splitting this into 2 separate rules, except as a last resort. Is there any way of doing this? Perhaps with some hacky (exist) statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate object-0 
   (slot value))
CLIPS>    
(deftemplate object-1 
   (slot value))
CLIPS> 
(defrule example-1
   (or (object-0 (value ?x&:(> ?x 1)))
       (object-1 (value ?y&:(> ?y 2))))
   =>)
CLIPS> 
(defrule example-2
   (or (and (object-0 (value ?x))
            (test (> ?x 1)))
       (and (object-1 (value ?y))
            (test (> ?y 2))))
   =>)
CLIPS> 
(defrule example-3
   (exists (or (object-0 (value ?x&:(> ?x 1)))
               (object-1 (value ?y&:(> ?y 2)))))
   =>)
CLIPS> (assert (object-0 (value 3)) (object-1 (value 4)))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      example-1: f-2
0      example-2: f-2
0      example-1: f-1
0      example-3: *
0      example-2: f-1
For a total of 5 activations.
CLIPS>
```